# Show result of apex repeat in single row

Tags: visualforce, repeat, table

```
  <table>
         <apex:repeat value="{!dataList}" var="List" id="dataTable">
            <tr>  
               <th>   Name </th>
               <th>   Status</th>
            </tr>
             <tr>  
               <td>   <apex:inputField value="{!List.Name}"/> </td>
               <td>    <apex:inputField value="{!List.Status__c}"/></td>
            </tr>

         </apex:repeat>
  </table>
```

I want all rows to display horizontally not vertically i.e. in the same line one after another instead of in next line. How can this be done? The headings and values, both should be repeated horizontally.

Answer (score 2):

Just change the position of tr tag outside `apex:repeat`

```
<table>
    <tr> 
         <apex:repeat value="{!dataList}" var="List" id="dataTable">

               <td>   <apex:inputField value="{!List.Name}"/> </td>
               <td>    <apex:inputField value="{!List.Status__c}"/></td>

         </apex:repeat>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: it's not working.

Comment: @kanishka share your updated code with the screenshot of UI.